# Trouble installing Fake Sendmail

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail.exe

I am trying to install Fake Sendmail in Windows 8 using Google SMTP for testing PHP's mail() function. What am I doing wrong here?

My sendmail.ini

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=enteryourdomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; to force the sender to always be the following email address, uncomment and
; populate with a valid email address.  this will only affect the "MAIL FROM"
; command, it won't modify the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=myemail@gmail.com

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

;hostname=
```

My PHP.INI

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = you@yourdomain

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "C:\usr\lib\sendmail.exe -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
;mail.add_x_header = On

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log =
```

And Finally, my sendmail error log after my most recent test

```
13/09/12 07:23:32 : Socket Error # 10060<EOL>Connection timed out.
13/09/12 07:31:54 : Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this guide.  It worked for me after attempting other methods.
http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp

Just make sure you have the path to sendmail.exe in your system path and that in stunnel.conf you only have one client service active at a time.  You can use Gmail but I chose to use another smtp mail service provider.